# reading, storing and reusing a single item from a remote JSON file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I've just spent a few hours trying out about 10 different ways of getting this to work that I could find here on SO and on the web but I just can't crack it.

Basically i'm trying to do 3 things, some of which I have managed to do...

1) Read and import a remote JSON file (done)
2) Convert **only one** item from the returned data into a PHP string
3) Use that string in the rest of my script (this I know how to do).

It's just the second step that I can't work out.

Here is an example of my JSON file :

```
 {
"data": {
    "admin": "admin@foobar.com",
    "host": "00.000.000.000",
    "location": "Cloud",
    "server_id": "Server01",
    "server_start": "Tue, 28 Oct 2014 21:39:01 +0100",
    "server_start_iso8601": "2014-10-28T21:39:01+0100",
    "source": [
        {
            "listenurl": "http://00.000.000.000:9000/live",
            "server_description": "Description here",
            "server_name": "Name goes here",
            "server_url": "http://www.foobar.com"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I'm using the following to import it and dump the array (but i'm sure this may be where i'm going wrong as it is printing the entire array).

```
$url = 'http://www.foobar.com/JSON.txt';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

I've tried lots of way to display only the **"server_name"** part of the JSON file but with no success at all. I won't bother posting all the different ways i've tried as they have all be wrong.

All I want to do is grab the contents of **"server_name"** and assign it to a php string ($serverNAME) so I can then use that string in the rest of my script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it you should be able to get away with something like this:

```
$data = "Your JSON input";
$decoded = json_decode( $data );
// Take a look at your data:
var_dump( $decoded );
// Keep in mind that source is an array and will be
// returned as one but it contains objects.
$server_name = $decoded->data->source[ 0 ]->server_name;
// Note that json_decode will return an object by default
// you may pass in a boolean true as second argument to
// make it return an assoc array.
$decoded = json_decode( $data, true );
$server_name = $decoded[ 'data' ][ 'source' ][ 0 ][ 'server_name' ];
```

Or is this one of the approaches you tried earlier?

Pass in your input into [an online version of json_decode](https://de.functions-online.com/json_decode.html) and have a look at what it returns, then work your way through.
That plus var_dump and print_r are your best friends when you deal with data structures you cant wrap your head around.

Comment: Thank you so much to all three of you that all supplied the correct answer. I can totally understand it now. Before I was fishing what I thought were the relevant bits of code out of other answers & tutorials but none were working. Stripped down to it's basics I totally get it now! Thanks again guys :)

Comment: And a big bah humbug to the person that voted my question down, at Christmas too! tut tut tut

Answer (score 1):

Similar to denoir's answer, but using the array method if that is to your liking:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
$serverName = $json['data']['source'][0]['server_name'];
echo  $serverName;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://www.foobar.com/JSON.txt';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$decoded = json_decode($test, true);
$server_name = $decoded['data']['source'][0]['server_name'];
```

'source' is returned as an array, so you need the [0] index to access it.